# поиск по городам

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(function(){
    $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
        if(this.value.length >= 2){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "post/seocity.php", //Путь к обработчику
                data: {'referal':this.value},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
                }
            })
        }
    })

    $(".search_result").hover(function(){
        $(".who").blur(); //Убираем фокус с input
    })

    //При выборе результата поиска, прячем список и заносим выбранный результат в input
    $(".search_result").on("click", "li", function(){
        var s_user = $(this).text();
        $(".who").val(s_user).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //деактивируем input, если нужно
        $(".search_result").fadeOut();
        console.log(s_user);
    })

})
```

сделал такой поиск по городам, теперь не могу средиректить, что бы к моему урлу добавился город который выбрали в поиске

Comment: Так а что не получается? Я не вижу в вашем коде редиректа

Comment: document.location.href = s_user; собственно вот

Comment: мне нужно регуляркой отсеять пробелы, и большие буквы маленькие сделать